# Cassandra is not connect able after restart

Tags: cassandra

After restart my cassandra node does not start anymore. Ends with following error message.

```
ERROR 18:39:37 Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! findkita.kitas
java.lang.AssertionError: We shouldn't have got there is the base row had no associated entry
```

cassandra has heavy cpu usage and use 2,1 gb of memory there is be 1gb more available. I run nodetool cleanup and repair, but did not help.

I have 5 materialzied views on this table, but the amount of rows in table is under 2000, that is not much.

The cassandra runs in a docker container. The container is access able, but can not call cqlsh and my website cound not connect too

How can I fix the error? Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: The problem you've encountered is an internal error in cassadra. You didn't mention what version you're running, but you should either consider upgrading to the newest (in case it's fixed), or report it to the cassandra Jira ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA/ ) for triage.

Comment: I use verion 3.7 it is the latest version, isn't it?

Comment: 3.7 is newest, though 3.8/3.9 will be out "soon". Like I suggested, perhaps open a jira. However, with 2GB of RAM, it's likely you're filling the heap, perhaps there's an exception or so hiding behind the scenes stopping you from properly building the view.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really fix it, but I get it run. My first container is now complitly crashed and is not start able anymore. But I had same problem with other container, that are enter able. I run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade and get cassandra work again.

It is not importand if there are any upgrades, only to run the command make cassandra call able again. Have to do it at each restart, but better as a completle crashed database.